# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.admin.clucky, PID: 1864

Tags: android

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.admin.clucky, PID: 1864
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.clucky/com.example.admin.clucky.fetaldevelopments2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #189: Binary XML file line #189: Error inflating class

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9082812 byte allocation with 8445752 free bytes and 8MB until OOM

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Fetal development week by week"
        android:id="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FF060505"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView23"
        android:background="@drawable/f21"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:text="21 weeks
```

Your baby's movements have gone from flutters to full-on kicks and jabs against the walls of your womb. You may start to notice patterns as you become more familiar with her activity.
Your baby is the size of a carrot

"
            android:textColor="#FF060505"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold|normal|italic"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:text="22 weeks
```

Your baby now looks almost like a miniature newborn. Features such as lips and eyebrows are more distinct, but the pigment that will color his eyes isn't present yet.
Your baby is the size of a spaghetti squash.

"
            android:textColor="#FF060505"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold|normal|italic"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:text="23 weeks
```

Your baby's ears are getting better at picking up sounds. After birth, she may recognize some noises outside the womb that she's hearing inside now.
Your baby is the size of a large mango.

"
            android:textColor="#FF060505"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold|normal|italic"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

```
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Most probably you have an error in the xml. Post your layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.clucky/com.example.admin.clucky.fetaldevelopments2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #189: Binary XML file line #189: Error inflating class
```

please check  the fetaldevelopments2 Binary XML file line #189.

Comment: Binary XML file #189 means can i check fetaldevelopment.xml file